# Tangent half angle formula proof

Tags: trigonometry

Using angle sum-difference, double, and/or triple angle relations with tangent, cosine, and sine, need help proving tangent half-angle relations. Thanks!

Comment: Your title helped me get to the correct wikipedia page.

Answer (score 3):

You can find these proofs on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_identities).

Comment: Man I searched the entire internet for this and its on wikipedia? Thank you for posting this. I just did not understand why the "usual" tangent half-angle identity tan x/2 = (1-cos x)/ sin x is true. Thanks!